# What does string array[] = ""; mean and why does it work?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
string array[] = "";
```

How am I able to assign a `const char*` to an array? Is that the same as:

```
string array[] = {""};
```

?? That would make sense to me. However, this still doesn't work

```
int array[] = 5;
```

So what is the difference between them that it doesn't work for `int` arrays?

Comment: That shouldn't compile. There are some special rules to allow you to initialise a character array from a string literal; but not an array of anything else.

Comment: What is the type of `string`?  If it's `std::string` (as it should be), then your first line shouldn't compile.  If it's `typedef char string;`, however, this would be the classical initialization of a `char[]`.

Comment: And of course, the type of `""` isn't `char const*`, but `char const [1]`.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is a `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect code; it is a bug in your compiler (possibly gcc/g++?) to accept it.

clang gives the following error ([link](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22#include%20%3Cstring%3E%5Cnstd%3a%3astring%20a%5B%5D%20=%20%5C%22%5C%22;%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/clang++%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O2%22%7D%5D%7D)):

```
a.cpp:5:17: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
    std::string array[] = "";
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Visual C++ agrees ([link](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/QXEl)):

```
testvc.cpp(2) : error C3074: an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list
```

The relevant clause in the standard is 8.5p17:

> [...] 
>   — If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of char16_t, an array of char32_t, or an array of wchar_t, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2. 
>   [...]
>   — Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed. 
>   [...]

Submitted to gcc as a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60009

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that functionality is a carryover  from the initialization of empty `char` arrays.(`std::string` acts very similar to `char`.)

`char buf[10] = "";` is equivalent to `char buf[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`, but `char buf[10] = "a";` is equivalent to `char buf[10] = {'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`.  Why?  Since `char` is an arithmetic value, it is auto-initialized to zero.

Your compiler sees `""` as a `char` value (`const char*`, technically) and simply casts it to an `std::string`.  While this is not exactly up to standard, it works on most compilers.