# Extra curly braces while initializing a string

Tags: c++, initialization

According to question [What does string array[] = ""; mean and why does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481462/what-does-this-code-mean-and-why-does-it-work) I want to ask what difference between *s1* and *s2* in the code below:

```
int main() {
    const char* s1 = { "Hello" }; // strange but work as followed
    const char* s2 = "Hello"; // ordinary case 
    return 0;
}
```

Why extra curly braces are permitted? Any reference to C++ standard will be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++98 (and C++03) this is pretty simple; in clause 8.5:

> 14 - If `T` is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form
>   `T x = { a };`
>   is equivalent to
>   `T x = a;`

In C++11 this is covered by list-initialization (8.5.4p3):

> [...] if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or
>   its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element [...]

I *think* this is the same question as [Initializing scalars with braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232184/initializing-scalars-with-braces?lq=1).

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is: because the standard says so.  §8.5.2/1:

> A char array (whether plain char, signed char, or unsigned
>   char), char16_t array, char32_t array, or wchar_t array can
>   be initialized by a narrow character literal, char16_t
>   string literal, char32_t string literal, or wide string
>   literal, respectively, **or by an appropriately-typed string
>   literal enclosed in braces**.  Successive characters of the
>   value of the string literal initialize the elements of the
>   array.

(That's C++11, but earlier versions said the same thing, minus
the references to the new types.)

The reason this is allowed is because C allowed it.  As to why
C allowed it, I have no idea.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's irrelevant (and somewhat contentious); the standard is referring to the object being initialized, which is not a string literal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The type _getting initialized_ here is a pointer ("scalar type"), not an array ("aggregate type"). So the cited text is irrelevant to the question. Another answer is citing the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: `s1` is a scalar, not an array. 8.5.2/1 doesn't apply here.