# initialize char array with quotes and curly braces

Tags: c++, arrays, initializing

I'm little confused. What is the logically difference between these codes?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char a[5]="ABCD"; // this
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Second is

```
char a[5]={"ABCD"}; // this
```

Third is

```
char a[5]={'A','B','C','D'}; // this
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21482059/509868 (specifically about the second piece of code)

Answer (score 6):

```
char a[5]={"ABCD"};
char a[5]={'A','B','C','D','\0'};
```

In both cases, the array of characters **a** is declared with a size of 5 elements of type char: the 4 characters that compose the word **"ABCD"**, plus a final null character **('\0')**, which specifies the end of the sequence and that, in the second case, when using double quotes (") it is appended automatically.Attention adding null character separating via commas. A series of characters enclosed in double quotes ("") is called a *string constant*. The C compiler can automatically add a null character `'\0'` at the end of a string constant to indicate the end of the string.

Source:[This link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/) can help you better

Comment: why third one is not adding null char automatically? or why the first 2 methods adding null automatically?

Comment: AFAIK, compiler knows adding `NULL` when you compose an array using quotes.

Comment: I know that, but why compiler not adding null in the 3rd method? any logic?

Comment: IMHO, 3rd method is to see elements of array one-by-one, to indicate `NULL`

Comment: String literals are NULL terminated by definition. A comma separated set of four chars is just a blob of data, the compiler has no idea it's intended to be a string.

Comment: patros Great One..!! @NewCoder sorry if I bothered you, but I was confused..!!

Answer (score 0):

The first two are assignment of a `char[5]` source to a `char[5]` array with different syntax only. (the 5 being the four letters plus a null terminator)

The last one will also do the same, but it doesn't explicitly specify a null terminator. Since you are assigning to a `char[5]`, the last one will still zero-fill the remaining space, effectively adding a null terminator and acting the same, but the last one will not throw a compiler error if you assign to a `char[4]`; it will just leave you with an unterminated array of characters.

Comment: why third one is not adding null char automatically? or why the first 2 methods adding null automatically?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq This answer says that the third one does add the null char - it's not right to ask why it doesn't!

Comment: @anatolyg I just asked that, why compiler not adding null char automatically?  char a[5]={'A','B','C','D','\0'}; any logic?

Comment: "Why does the sun not shine?" - incorrect question: the sun does shine. "Why does the compiler not add 0 in `char a[5]={'A','B','C','D'}`?" - incorrect question: the compiler does add it. Sorry for the metaphor; I hope it's clear now.

Comment: It's just that the null terminator is not actually coming from a string literal in the third case, it's only there because there is extra space in the buffer that is being filled with zero.